# $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq c|x - y|$, with $0 < c < 1$, implies $(f^n(x_0))_n$ converges to a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq c|x - y|$, with $0 < c < 1$.  Prove that for all $x_0, (f^n(x_0))_n$ converges to a unique fixed point.

*Note: This is the Contraction Mapping Theorem, of which proofs are readily available.  My question is to verify or critique* my *proof*.

**Lemma 1:** By induction, for all $n \geq 1, j \geq 0, |f^{n+j-1}(x) - f^{n+j}(x)| \leq c^j|f^{n-1}(x) - f^{n}(x)|.$

**Lemma 2:** For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n$ such that $|f^{n-1}(x) - f^{n}(x)| < \varepsilon $.  This follows directly from Lemma 1, since $c^n \to 0$ for large $n$.

We now show that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n$ such that for all $m,|f^n(x) - f^{n+m}(x)| < \varepsilon$. Choose $n$ such that $|f^{n-1}(x) - f^{n}(x)| < (1-c)\varepsilon$. Then for all $m$:

$$
\begin{align*}
|f^n(x) - f^{n+m}(x)| & \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{m} |f^{n+j-1}(x) - f^{n+j}(x)| \quad \text{(by triangle inequality)} \\
& \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{m} c^j|f^{n-1}(x) - f^{n}(x)| \quad \text{(by Lemma 1)} \\
& < \sum_{j = 1}^{m}c^j(1-c)\varepsilon \\
& < \frac 1 {1-c} {(1-c)\varepsilon} \\
& < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
$$

Thus, $(f^n(x))_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges to a limit $\ell$.  Since $f$ is clearly continuous, $\ell := \lim f^n(x) = \lim f(f^n(x)) = f(\lim f^n(x)) = f(\ell)$ is a fixed point.

This fixed point $\ell$ is unique.  Assume $f(a) = a, f(b) = b, a \neq b$.  Then $|a - b| = |f(a) - f(b)| \leq c|a - b|$, a contradiction.  Thus, $f^n(x) \to \ell$ for all $x$.

**Questions:**

1. Is the proof correct? Please provide any critique or suggestions, on the proof or its writing.

2. I know that the my initial attempt to prove uniqueness of fixed point ($|f^n(x_0) - f^n(x_1)| \leq c^n|f(x_0) - f(x_1)| \to 0$) can't be used to build a proof, but request some clarification as to why not.  If any two points in $\mathbb{R}$ end up going to the same point $y$, isn't that $y$ a fixed point for any $x_0$?  The counter example is $x \mapsto k + \frac 1 x$, suggesting that the points can become arbitrarily close but not fixed; but I'd appreciate some clarification here.

*Perhaps the answer to #2 is: The last line shows that any two points in $\mathbb{R}$ end up arbitrarily close.  That does *not* mean they end up fixed.  Only once we've already shown that in the limit each one individually is fixed, and yet are arbitrarily close, can we conclude that they are equal.  Is this correct? How should I clarify the last line to capture this?*

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $f$? Otherwise, this proof, at a glance, looks almost identical to the standard proof of the theorem I have seen.

Comment: @legionwhale Edited to show $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  Glad to hear this proof looks good, although it's clearly incomplete, as I've yet to prove the same fixed point for _all_ $x_0$.  How is the exposition?

Comment: The exposition is quite brief (the suitability of that depends on the audience, I guess) but clear (perhaps clearer if you don't reuse $m$ for something slightly different in Lemma 2?). A couple of issues. You say $c^m$ vanishes for sufficiently large $m$. To me, "$c^m$ vanishes" means $c^m = 0$. I think $c^m \to 0$ would be more standard. More importantly, what is the significance of $|f^m(x) - f^{n+m}(x)| < \varepsilon$? Even just one more sentence here is probably crucial, especially since the result does not hold in every domain/codomain, which I tried to hint at in the earlier comment.

Comment: @legionwhale Thanks, invaluable suggestions.  I've fixed up the usage of $n$ and $m$, added that $|f^m(x) - f^{n+m}(x)| < \varepsilon$ means its Cauchy, and tackled showing that the fixed point is unique.  Can you take a look?

Comment: I don't follow how your edits prove the fixed point is unique. Besides, you can prove this uniqueness very simply by proof by contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure what your counterexample is since $x \mapsto k + \frac{1}{x}$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. I also don't follow the argument of the uniqueness of the fixed point (the result you're using doesn't hold, or at least, it's not obvious). You can come up with a valid similar argument assuming existence. There is an even simpler argument, which also assumes existence, as the above comment alludes to.

Comment: You don't need induction for uniqueness as $0\leq |l-p|=|f(l)-f(p)|\leq c|l-p|$ and $c \in (0,1)$ combine to imply $|l-p|=0$. As for why $|f^n(x_0) - f^n(x_1)| \leq c^n|f(x_0) - f(x_1)| \to 0$ alone can't be used for the existence part of the proof (I assume this is what is meant in your 2nd Q): as it should, the argument relies on the fact that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ ($d(x,y):=|x-y|$) is a complete metric space and $f$ is a self-map. We play this geometric sum game to say that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy which means $|x_n-x_m|  \to 0$ and is not necessarily satisfied just because $|x_n-x_{n+1}| \to 0$.

Comment: @dezdichado @ legionwhale: I intended to prove uniqueness as follows: If $f^n(a) \to \ell_a, f^n(b) \to \ell_b,$ and $f^n(a) - f^n(b) \to 0$, then $\ell_a=\ell_b$. Is that argument incorrect? Is there a counterexample? Or is correct but needs to be written better?

Comment: It looks like you are confusing two things: Proving any two fixed points are equal and proving for any initial $x_0$, the iteration converges to same $l.$ You can do both of them separately, but we are saying that the first proof is much simpler.

Comment: @dezdichado Got it! Clarifying that that's needed is to prove that if there are fixed points, they must be the same - and not that any two points iterated will have the same limit -- removed the obstacle, and I was able to complete the proof.

Comment: Rudin , I still Remeber this Our proffessor was teaching equicontinuty after that he proceed to this it's called contraction(may be not sure I had forgotten)  but it's in Rudin and it was asked many times In end seems of our college.